# Getting Javascript to omit anchor tags in new window for external link script

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, external, anchor

I've been beating my head against the wall for a bit as I know the answer is simple but it eludes me.  I have some programming experience but mainly with PHP.  I came across an instance in which a site I am working on needed a script to automatically detect external links and open them in a new window.  I found 2 separate javascript codes and they work beautifully but the problem is where there is an anchor tag such as href="#B" the code considers this an external link.  I've done significant research and tried doing an indexOf and endWith() functions but neither are ignoring a link that has a #letter (i.e. #B).

Would be great if I could get some further assistance or pointers.  See the code below I found on the net:

```
assigntarget:function(){
var rexcludedomains=new RegExp(this.excludedomains.join("|"), "i")
var all_links=document.getElementsByTagName("a")
if (this.mode=="auto" || (this.mode=="manual" && this.togglebox.checked)){
    for (var i=0; i<=(all_links.length-1); i++){
        if (all_links[i].hostname.search(rexcludedomains)==-1 &&  all_links[i].href.indexOf("http:")!=-1)
            all_links[i].target=ddwindowlinks.linktarget
    }
}
else{
    for (var i=0; i<=(all_links.length-1); i++)
        all_links[i].target=""
}
```

Now I've tried using index as I mentioned above to find if # exists in the link as below:

```
    for (var i=0; i<=(all_links.length-1); i++){
        if (all_links[i].hostname.search(rexcludedomains)==-1 &&  all_links[i].href.indexOf("#") ==-1 && all_links[i].href.indexOf("http://") !=-1)
            all_links[i].target=ddwindowlinks.linktarget
```

Thanks for any help or potiners.

Comment: What is the value of this.excludedomains?

Comment: Annie has a point. Is the current site you are on in the excluded domains? A # normally gets translated to `http://siteyouareon.com/pageyouareon.html#....`

Comment: value is - excludedomains: ["yourdomain.com", "google.com"],  I've tried #B and I've tried # in the excluded domains but it still doesn't.  I am using wordpress and I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.  All of the wordpress template anchors I use are fine such as the anchor that brings the page back to the top.  But the glossary of terms I am using from another site's anchor tags are recognized as external links.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just strip out the anchor tag

```
var str = str.replace(/#.*$/, "")
```

and test against that. I'd be interested to see exactly what `this.excludedomains.join("|")` equals and which exact links it fails against, though.

Comment: Those are preset at the top.  You can manually set domains for it to fail against. var ddwindowlinks={
//1)Enter domains to be EXCLUDED from opening in new window:
excludedomains: ["yourdomain.com", "google.com"],'

Comment: If I am reading that correctly it will only remove the special character /# .  I do not think that will work. as there will still be href=B in which the code would think that is an external link too.  Again understand I am not that familiar with Javascript syntax so I could be wrong.